# Need 'votes' filter on 'new' tab for default tag searches

Tags: feature-request, sorting, new-nav

With the new navigation, when you do a tag search only from the search box it takes you to the **new** tab with a filter of **custom tags** and the **newest** sort order. It can be pretty important to be able to sort these by votes, especially when dupe-hunting.

Please add a **votes** sort to the **new** tab.

Answer (score 3):

Workaround: clicking on "popular" then choosing "votes" will allow you to get that view without using the tag.

It should be more consistent for a tag search from the search box to redirect you to your current tab (which is the analogous of the old nav behavior).

I don't agree with adding a "votes" sort to the "new" tab, because then that tab certainly would show you old material and not recent activity.

Comment: a) I just tried that on the tag 'top-bar' and when I switched over to popular, all the questions went away. I guess you must have some minimum requirements for popular. We really need a page for questions in general with no requirements, that can then be filtered and sorted. b) I never did get a reply to my comment on the Alpha 2 post about what defines 'new'.

Comment: a) did you chose "votes"? Did you try and refresh? There's only ~2k users on the new nav right now and you are going to hit empty caches very often b) new (tab): newly asked or newly modified

Comment: a) Yes, I chose "votes", I also tried refreshing. b) I was meaning what is the timeframe for new.

Comment: a) can you go to the bottom of the page and copy paste the "permalink" you will find? b) there is no time frame it's either a sort (for new and active) or a "last 3000" selection based on activity in the case of "recommended"

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=popular&show=today&sort=votes&page=1&pageSize=50&excerpts=compact&tags=top-bar&mode=any

Comment: Ok, you were filtering by "today". There are no questions created today in that tag. To see "all time" -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/?show=alltime&tags=top-bar