# It does not seem possible to sort all questions in a tag by votes

Tags: feature-request, tags, sorting, new-nav

We can't [sort by votes on the new tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259280/need-votes-filter-on-new-tab-for-default-tag-searches):

[image: No option for votes]

Even changing the URL manually:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/new/privacy?show=all&sort=votes

quietly converts the sort order to:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/new/privacy?show=all&sort=recentlyactive

I [agree with Sklivvz](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259281/1438) that it seems strange that the top result on the "new" tab might be very old if sorting by votes. But that didn't stop me from being unpleasantly surprised that the sort option was not available. Maybe [orthogonality is overrated](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/marthag/text/humor/lwall.html):

> Any computer scientist who praises orthogonality should be sentenced to
> use an Etch-a-Sketch.
> —Larry Wall

It is possible to [sort by votes on the popular tab for all time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/popular/privacy?show=alltime&sort=votes), but that does not seem to show all questions:

[image]

So while there is a way to sort *most questions* by votes, it does not seem possible to sort *all questions in a tag* by votes. I'm not sure which questions are excluded from the "popular" tab, however. Perhaps the solution is to remove whatever non-time-based filter is applied to popular questions when sorting by votes.

Comment: One reason I switched back to the old(er) nav, and prolly the biggest reason, was that I couldn't effectively sort by votes. This has a +1 from me.

Comment: Depending on how one wants to look at the current situation, this question is either [tag:status-completed], as [we can sort the questions in a tag by votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy?tab=Votes) or should be closed as not reproducible, as the specific pages which are linked in the question are no longer available on the site.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Instead of capitalizing the word "enter" in "enter image description here", it might be better to just remove those words entirely.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist While I agree that capitalizing "Enter" was of little value, it's better to not remove the "enter image description here" text, as it can be used to search for image alt-text which still needs to be updated to an actual description of what the image is displaying. The best thing to do would be to replace the "enter image description here" with text which actually describes what the image is showing/attempting to illustrate, so that those who can't see the image can get at least an idea about what the image shows.

Comment: @Makyen Certainly. In this case, I felt that the surrounding text gives enough context that the image description could even be omitted. Perhaps I'm still mistaken, though...

Answer (score 1):

The newest tab implies a sort by date IMHO. With the option you select in the sort dropdown you only choose what date to sort by. Sorting by votes doesn't have anything to do with the date a question was added/modified/answered. The only thing that would make sense in this context would be to sort the questions by the date the last vote was made to it or any of it's answers (as opposed to the amount of votes which is one of the popularity measurements).

Comment: Hmmm... I thought the idea was that the tabs and the sort order were orthogonal. When I read the tabs (from right to left) I think: "need answers" is for when I want to help someone, "popular" is when I want to read something interesting/important, and "new" is unfiltered. In other words, I think of the tabs as filters and not really anything at all to do with sorting. In any case, there seems to be no way to get an unfiltered view of questions sorted by votes, which seems a common use case.